# GroovyScriptEngine roots or url parameter confusion

Tags: spring, groovy, classpath

I'm trying Groovy in an enterprise Java application. In the application Spring is used heavily. I've started with a unit test to see how to initialize GroovyScriptEngine. The project structure is a bit complex. I'll try to make it simple.
`module1`, `module2`, `module3` are the maven modules. There is `module0` which is the root module, parent of all.

In JUnit, I'm calling it like this:

```
GroovyScriptEngine groovyScriptEngine = new GroovyScriptEngine("module1/module2/module3/src/main/resources/META-INF/scripts");
```

This string parameter goes to `GroovyScriptEngine`'s `roots` field as
 `D:/myProjects/module0/module1/module2/module3/src/main/resources/META-INF/scripts`.

It is not a problem so far.
I deployed the application. Defined the `url` parameter like this:

```
<bean id="groovyScriptEngine" class="groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine">
    <constructor-arg name="url" value="${core.groovy.roots}"/>
</bean>
```

where
`core.groovy.roots=module1/module2/module3/src/main/resources/META-INF/scripts`

At initialization, I'm tracking the url parameter, it goes to the same place like this:

`D:/servers/tools/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/bin/module1/module2/module3/src/main/resources/META-INF/scripts`

I've also tried to give `classpath*:/META-INF/scripts` to same paramter but it didn't work too:

`D:/servers/tools/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/bin/classpath*:/META-INF/scripts`

How can I make the reference relative and also make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `GroovyScriptEngine`, you can compile your Groovy code with the rest of your Java sources, and use it just like any other Java class.

`GroovyScriptEngine` makes sense when your Groovy code needs to be interpreted dynamically, and without restarting the application after script changes. For example, you can have an external source of scripts.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but the situation is just like you said. I need dynamic behavior of the scripts.